# about high-dimensional regression data

Tags: bigdata, dimensionality-reduction

I am doing experiments on the high-dimensional regression. However, it is hard to obtain the practical or synthetic high-dimensional data. I have checked on UCI website as well as some papers with related to this topic. Currently, I have not obtained satisfactory datasets.

Could someone give me some hints on how to search and obtain the high-dimensional data? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Please check this website: **http://dataportals.org/**, its a collection of data portals from around the world. Might find here what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the big list of data repositories, check one of them http://www.kdnuggets.com/datasets/index.html